# Reference another projects config file at debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, web-config

I have two projects in a solution in Visual Studio 2010, Project1 and Project2.

Project1 is the parent project and has a config file called ConnectionStrings.config that contains connection strings used by both projects.

I have added the ConnectionStrings.config file from Project1 into Project2 as a linked file.

When I publish this to our webserver it works fine, Project2 can read data in from our database using the connection strings from the config file in Project1.

When I'm working on local and debug Project2 I get the following error which I assume means that it can't see the linked file:

> Unable to open configSource file 'ConnectionStrings.config'.
>   (C:\Project2\web.config line 10)

**Project1 ConnectionStrings.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=***;Initial Catalog=***;Integrated Security=False; Password=***;User ID=***"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

**Project2 web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
    <connectionStrings configSource="ConnectionStrings.config"/>
</configuration>
```

How can I get Project2 to read this config file from Project1?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

NO, I don't think you can do that. If you really want the same connection string to be shared across multiple project then consider having that connection string specified in `machine.config` rather.